# Exec in Bash /bin/kill not found

Tags: bash, shell, sh, exec

I am migrating a script that was just using sh to bash, the script originally looked like this:

```
 #!/bin/sh
 ... a bunch of setup ...
 exec "$@"
```

When I run the script via:

```
./my_script kill -l
```

I get a list of available signals:

```
HUP INT QUIT ILL TRAP ABRT BUS FPE KILL USR1 SEGV USR2 PIPE ALRM TERM STKFLT
CHLD CONT STOP TSTP TTIN TTOU URG XCPU XFSZ VTALRM PROF WINCH POLL PWR SYS
```

However, I want to use the bash signal names, so I thought I could simply:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec bash -l "$@"
```

The problem is now kill is not recognized:

```
/bin/kill: /bin/kill: cannot execute binary file
```

Really my script is just a wrapper around another process and I need to make sure a signal of `kill -SIGTERM` can be sent to it.

Comment: Not sure to see the problem. When I create a script with only the shebang for bash and the only line : exec "$@"...../my_script kill -l works perfectly and I obtain the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are telling bash to run a file which it expects to be a bash script but it turns out to be a binary executable file.

Instead of this:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec bash -l "$@"
```

Use this:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec bash -c "$1"
```

Is there a specific reason you need option `-l` to run bash as a "login" shell? If not just use option `-c` to run the string argument.

Updated to use `$1` instead of `$@` as it is more appropriate for a string argument as @chepner commented.

This also requires you to send the argument as a string, not a reference to the binary.

Instead of this:

```
./my_script kill -l
```

Do this:

```
./my_script "kill -l"
```

Comment: If you are passing a single string, you should definitely use `$*` (or better, `$1`) instead of `$@`, since you really don't want multiple arguments passed to `bash`, just the one argument for the `-c` option.

Comment: I'm actually sending in another script to `./myscript ./my_other_scipt` - does that change your opinion on using `$1`?

Comment: @Anthony Certainly use `$1` in that case. Don't try to use any extra arguments you aren't expecting that a caller might mistakenly (or intentionally) pass.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the `-c` option.  Otherwise (see the ARGUMENTS section of the `bash` man page) "...the first argument is assumed to be the name of a file containing shell commands."

I.e.:

```
exec bash -lc "$*"
```

Comment: You probably want `$*` here; otherwise, `exec bash -lc kill -l` will treat `-l` as the value of `$0` in the `bash` command, and `kill` won't receive any arguments. (Of course, `$*` could be wrong for different reasons, which is why writing this kind of wrapper is fragile.)